# Diagonalizable Matrices with a Row of 0's

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have two matrices, each contains a row of 0. I need to determine of these matrices are diagonalizable or not. According to the answers in the book, they are not. I don't understand why. I ran them in MAPLE, and got enough eigenvectors so the geometrical multiplicity is equal to the algebraic one. Therefore they should be diagonalizable. Can you please explain it to me? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: For a 3x3-matrix, you need 3 *linearly independent* eigenvectors.

Comment: Oh, so the vector (0,0,0) did come up as a eigenvector, but it is dependent of the other two and therefore the group of 3 eigenvectors is linearly dependent?

Comment: By definition, an eigenvector is a nonzero vector.

Comment: Apparently Maple returns (0,0,0) as an eigenvector but we usually exclude the zero vector. Of course the zero vector trivially satisfies $A.0=0$ but it doesn't contribute to what you're looking for: a basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: It appears that your tool will give you zero-filled columns if there are too few independent eigenvectors to fill out a square matrix. That would just be a quirk in its output format -- the zero vector is, by definition, never an eigenvector.

Answer (score 2):

Both matrices are triangular, so that you can read their eigenvalues on the main diagonal (no need of Maple or whatever math software to do this).

For the first one, the eigenspace associated with $\lambda=1$ has dimension 1, and the same for $\lambda=0$, so that the sum of the dimensions of the eigenspaces is $<3$. Hence, this matrix is not diagonalizable.

Same story for the second matrix.

Comment: Thank you. Is there a generalizing rule about matrices with a row of 0's, or are there also diagonalizable matrices with a row of 0's?

Comment: @user2899944 The zero matrix is obviously diagonalizable. If you want a less trivial example, consider $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$.